# Restoring High Frame Rate Video After Forced Slow Motion Conversion

Tags: framerate, iphone, frame-interpolation

I'm dealing with a tricky situation involving high frame rate video recording and need some guidance. For an experiment, I needed to record a video at a high frame rate. The only way to achieve this on my iPhone was by using the slow motion setting, which records at 240 fps. However, the problem arose after transferring the video via AirDrop. The video automatically converted to 30 fps, and the slow motion effect became a permanent feature, eliminating the high frame rate I originally intended to capture. Additionally I have already lost the original video file, so I’m left only with the 30 fps version.

To salvage the situation, I used Flowframes to interpolate the video back to 240 fps. This step successfully restored the frame rate, but the video still retains the unwanted slow motion effect. My questions are:

1. How can I manually adjust the speed of the video to negate the slow motion effect and return it to normal playback speed? Is there a specific factor or method that should be used for this adjustment?
2. Could the conversion from 30 fps to 240 fps have impacted the video in a way that complicates restoring it to its original speed?

Any advice or solutions to revert my video to its intended high frame rate without the slow motion effect would be greatly appreciated!